# What is the name of a screw-nut ring used to hold up a hanging lampshade? (see photo)

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I have a hanging light fixture that I'm trying to put a lampshade on. Because the light fixture hangs from the ceiling, If I don't screw something underneath it, the lampshade would fall down.

The light fixture has screw threads, so I can use a screw ring to hold the lampshade up. But, I don't know the name for the screw-ring so I don't know how to shop for it.

I see in this photo of the light fixture next to a screw-ring-thing that is too small, what is the British name for the screw-ring?

[image: Light fixture next to a screw-ring-thingy]

Answer (score 3):

Try googling "shade ring".  I found quite a few that were of different sizes so you'd have to be more specific of the size.

Here's one I found  at 1000bulbs.com

[image]

Answer (score 1):

shade ring or lampholder skirt. They come in different sizes. If your lampholder is that style (with a low energy lamp) you'll need an E27 shade ring and a 40mm hole in the lampholder.

Ordinary standard Bayonet Cap lampholders are smaller diameter.