# What's a "shade nut"?

Tags: light-fixture

Can someone point to "the shade nut" with a real life picture? I'm assuming it's not a [shade ring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/175785).

> [I would **fit a disk of aluminum foil on top**, either over or under the **shade nut**. You could also use sheet metal, such as from the bottom of a coffee can. This disk should not extend all the way out to the shade wall--leave at least 1/2" for ventilation to prevent dangerous heat buildup. *Do not use tape or other combustible materials.* If you put the disk under the shade nut you could also use a standard or fender washer to prevent damage to the foil.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/211460/127008)

Is it this? See my red lines.

[image]

Comment: I would say the threaded fastener that secures a lamp shade to the lamp is likely to be what the author of that text means when they write "shade nut". But really, you're going about this the wrong way. You should post a comment under the answer you're quoting, and find out _exactly_ what the person who wrote the text meant. And yes, that means you'll have to spend a smidgen of extra time here building the reputation so that you're allowed to post a comment.

Comment: "Shade" = "Lamp Shade", so it's just the nut that fastens the shade.

Comment: Your red lines point exactly to the shade nut (as does the blue line & text describing what the blue line is pointing to), so I'm honestly a bit confused by what you're asking and why. You seem to have perfectly identified it on "real life pictures" (even if they were sourced from the internet, not pics from your house), so you should be able to transfer this to the lamp shades in your house. If your spacial relations are so challenged that you can't make that transfer (nothing personal, my wife's aren't that great), maybe you should consider _not_ doing home repairs yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of the question you linked to, Yes the nut you have illustrated with a red mark is a nut holding on a shade so we will call it a  shade nut.

**A "shade nut" is a nut that secures a lamp shade on a lamp.**

I do not know if that is the official name for that part, but it is a nut on a shade. They are referred to on [lamp parts websites](http://www.lampshop.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=ls&Category_Code=10_01c_PARTS_LSFITTING-PARTS_FINIALS) as a "[Finial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finial)" but a finial can be a design element on furniture or architecture and have nothing to do with being a nut or having threads.

**Now we can call your part a lamp shade finial.**

I do not have a lamp with shade so i can not provide a real life photo of a lamp finial.

Not all shade nuts or finials look that the one in your photo but they all do the same job, secure the shade to the lamp.

*This nut, Alaska Man, is going to go sit in the shade.*